# Github action Save images with CURL, it saves blank images

Tags: curl, github-actions, building-github-actions

I am trying to update app icon before building app using Github action using this  command

```yaml
 - name: add icon
   run: curl https://www.example.org/precomposed.png  >  android/app/src/main/res/drawable/ic_launcher_milla.png
```

This code make a black image or a blank image not the real image from url
How to fix this issue? [image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the issue is with curl? I tested it on publicly available file and all looks fine.

```yaml
name: Curl PNG

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]
  
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  run_tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
    - name: add icon
      run:  curl https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ca/a9/df/caa9df0ae36595e7d4b9961596adc218.png > some.png
    - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: my-artifact
        path: some.png
```

Comment: it is create a blank file only

Comment: do we need to add any code for wait to finish download?

Comment: Did you try to publish this file as artifact and check png? Did you try with another png file? You don't need to wait, curl is blocking here.

Comment: After finishing build i download the (artifact) apk file and decode it and i fount a black image not the remote image but it created new file with given name but it is a black image

Comment: I don't try with your example may be it is working but what i need is to replace the image and take the apk build using github

Comment: Why i ask for delay is it is showing as 0 sec  that is why i thing about the delay for example we are suing await for thred

Comment: I tried with diffrent image file and the result is same

Comment: i try to add jpg file and when i open that image it is showing as 'The file “newjog.jpg” could not be opened because it is empty.'

Comment: I understood. My point actually was to check with your file if this is sth related to download via curl, or not. Can you try to split that into 3 steps? First download your png file to some location. Second upload that file as artifact (to be sure that you download it correctly). Third copy that file to location where it can be used in your package.

Comment: I upload image as artifact and it is ok , but after that i move it to android folder but it is again blank image

Comment: I got a new solution and thankyou for supporting